# Forcing handshake signals on a serial port

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a piece of equipment that I control via an RS-232 serial interface. It has a basic binary protocol for sending commands and receiving results, including a command for powering it down. However, to power it up you cannot use a serial command since its UART is inactive. Instead you hold the two hardware handshake signals high for over a second and the device powers up.
I have been reading up on Microsoft's documentation and ended up with the code below. It does not throw any exceptions but does not work either. Obviously my app contains much more code than the below example but I believe it covers the gist of it. What am I missing?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")\]
internal static extern bool EscapeCommFunction(IntPtr hFile, uint dwFunc);

internal const uint SETRTS = 3;
internal const uint CLRRTS = 4;
internal const uint SETDTR = 5;
internal const uint CLRDTR = 6;

Port = new SerialPort("COM7" : comPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

object stream = typeof(SerialPort).GetField("internalSerialStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(Port);
SafeFileHandle handle = (SafeFileHandle)stream.GetType().GetField("\_handle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(stream);

IntPtr hFile = handle.DangerousGetHandle();

EscapeCommFunction(hFile, SETDTR);
EscapeCommFunction(hFile, SETRTS);
Thread.Sleep(1500);
EscapeCommFunction(hFile, CLRDTR);
EscapeCommFunction(hFile, CLRRTS);
```

I have tried setting the Handshake, DtrEnable, and RtsEnable properties to various values without seeing any difference.

Comment: Did you measure the pins to see if and what actually goes to high signal?

Comment: Why not try the same thing using C++ and the Win32API directly and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: This pinvoke doesn't do anything more than the Dtr/RtsEnable properties do.  Crucial is to set the Handshake property to Handshake.None so you can control the lines in software.  If that doesn't help then use a program like Putty to validate the wiring, port selection and device behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have measured the pins. The interface works just fine via Putty. The Handshake property has no effect on the behavior.